# Finding GPO speeds

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

Our Windows 7 computers are spending 50 seconds on the computer configuration portion of our GPO's each time they boot. (I [turned on Verbose info](http://soeteam.blogspot.com/2011/03/howto-turn-windows-7-please-wait-into.html)).

Is there a benchmark or profiling tool I can use to find out how long each individual GPO is taking to run?

Comment: I would start with a Process Monior boot trace before moving on the Windows Performance Recorder boot trace to grab an etl.

Comment: @HelpingHand Thanks, I'll give that a try Monday.

Comment: @HelpingHand Thanks, The issue was that one msi was trying and failing to install each time.